# Coded UI test click throws hidden control exception in windows 10 but works on windows 7

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I am using visual studio 2017 CUIT and trying to automate right click on my application icon present in the notification overflow area. With right click it shows exit menu item. It is then supposed to click on this item but fails throwing below exception. Whereas same code works fine on windows 7.

**Test method CodedUITestProject1.CodedUITest2.CodedUITestMethod1 threw exception:**

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.FailedToPerformActionOnHiddenControlException:
>   Cannot perform 'Click' on the hidden control. Additional Details: 
>   TechnologyName:  'MSAA' AccessibleName:  'Context' ClassName: 
>   '#32768' ControlType:  'Window'  --->
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT:
>   0xF004F002

**Below is the code snippet:**

```
public void RecordedMethod2()
    {
        #region Variable Declarations
        WinButton uINotificationChevronButton = this.UIItemWindow.UINotificationChevronButton;
        WinButton uIItemButton = this.UIItemWindow1.UIOverflowNotificationToolBar.UIItemButton;
        WinWindow uIItemWindow2 = this.UIItemWindow2;
        #endregion

        // Click 'Notification Chevron' button
        Mouse.Click(uINotificationChevronButton, new Point(15, 26));

        // Right-Click button numbered 3 in 'Overflow Notification Area' tool bar
        Mouse.Click(uIItemButton, MouseButtons.Right, ModifierKeys.None, new Point(25, 30));

        // Click window
        Mouse.Click(uIItemWindow2, new Point(608, 319));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the screen of your win7 machine have the same resolution as your win10 machine? You could try the Mouse.Click() method overload without the coordinates parameter, because using the same coordinates on different screen resolutions doesn't work that well.